# Convert Query from SQL server to SQLite Query

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I'm converting an existing application from an SQL Server database to SQLite I converted the tables and a lot of the queries but I couldn't convert this complex query and I need help

Here is my query:

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.name, c.phone, tr.price, tp.paid, tr.price - tp.paid AS debt, c.location, c.note, 
c.date
FROM Customers c CROSS apply (SELECT COALESCE (sum(tr.final), 0) AS price
FROM transfers tr
WHERE tr.cust_id = c.cust_id) tr CROSS apply
(SELECT COALESCE (sum(tp.value), 0) AS paid
FROM trans_payments tp
WHERE tp.cust_id = c.cust_id) tp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `APPLY` to a join on a derived table. This has exactly the same semantic in terms of summing and grouping

```sql
SELECT
    c.cust_id,
    c.name,
    c.phone, 
    tr.price,
    tp.paid,
    tr.price - tp.paid AS debt,
    c.location,
    c.note, 
    c.date
FROM Customers c
JOIN (
    SELECT tr.cust_id, COALESCE (sum(tr.final), 0) AS price
    FROM transfers tr
    GROUP BY tr.cust_id
) tr ON tr.cust_id = c.cust_id
JOIN (
    SELECT tp.cust_id, COALESCE (sum(tp.value), 0) AS paid
    FROM trans_payments tp
    GROUP BY tp.cust_id
) tp
ON tp.cust_id = c.cust_id
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, I'm getting this error: `no such column: tr.cust_id
Table - [Customers] column: cust_id, name, phone, location, note, date

Table - [transfers] column: ID, cust_id, price, discount, tax, final, tnumber, note, del_date, date, image

Table - [trans_payments] column: ID, cust_id, value, method, note, date`